# Spring method if annotated with @Transactional its not getting called

Tags: transactions, spring-transactions

Controller Code
@Autowired
    private AdNetworkPlacementService adNetworkPlacementService;

```
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public AdNetworkPlacement createPlacement(@QueryParam("pubId") Long publisherId, AdNetworkPlacement placement)
        throws APIException {

    return adNetworkPlacementService.createNonIntegratedAdNetworkPlacement(116l, publisherId, placement);
}
```

Method Code

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public AdNetworkPlacement createNonIntegratedAdNetworkPlacement(Long userId, Long publisherId, AdNetworkPlacement placement) throws APIException {
}
```

The method does not get called when added @Transactional

Commenting that it works fine

Comment: How did you make sure that createPlacement() method is getting called while createNonIntegratedAdNetworkPlacement() isn't ? by adding log statements or System.out.println?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved

It was problem with context-component:scan

Need to specify complete package structure